# Returning an index of an element in python if an element matches

Tags: python

I have an array, I need to return the index of an element if the target matches, without using the index().

For example we have a=[12,31,45,67,100,101].
If the target is 101, we will return 5, otherwise -1.

What I did is:

```
def target_meet(a,t):
   for i in range(len(a)):
      if a[i]==t:
          return i
   else:
          return -1
```

It gives me the wrong output.
Kindly help.

Thanks.

Comment: Your `for` loop looks to me like it should work - it can also be expressed with `enumerate`, as people are showing, but that's not going to correct your core issue. If you're getting the wrong response, the first thing I'd look at is whether you're comparing objects that are actually the same type - eg not a string representation being matched against an integer. Also make sure the `else` clause is fully out-dented to match the `for` block, not the `if` - or just drop it entirely and always return `-1` if you didn't return early from the loop.

Comment: Could you provide the sample input and the output it gave? Because the logic of your code is fine (the answers below are just different variations).

Comment: For the curious - this looks like it's (unnecessarily) using the relatively obscure `else` clause on for loops: http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/break_else.html That lets you specify a block that's executed if the loop finishes iteration but not if it exits early due to a `break`. If this example, say, set a local variable instead of returning it might be appropriate - 'record the index, breaking as soon as you see one, and set a default if you didn't see it at all' is one good use for `for/else`.

Comment: (Ok, that example is not quite a good use because setting the value to the default first and only modifying on a match is clearer. I'm reaching a little to demonstrate when you might use this feature.)

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://ideone.com/UvpvGT

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use enumerate :

> One line solution:

```
a=[12,31,45,67,100,101]

target=101

print([i if j==target else -1 for i,j in enumerate(a)])
```

output:

```
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 5]
```

> Detailed solution:

Above list comprehension is same as :

```
final_result=[]
for i,j in enumerate(a):
    if j==target:
        final_result.append(i)
    else:
        final_result.append(-1)

print(final_result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def target_meet(a,t):
  for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i]==t:
      return i
# return -1 after loop finished
  return -1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def target_meet(a,t):
   for i,x in enumerate(a):
      if x==t:
          return i
   return -1
```

Comment: `else:` should be removed and `return -1` unindented so it is reached when (if) the for loop ends

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but even if it finds the element still its returning -1, I don't need that -1 there.

Comment: @Adrija i just copied and pasted my answer into Ipython and it worked as expected. Did you miss something?

Comment: This is not all that different from their code. In python for loops support an else clause that is run after the for loop if the loop is never stopped with `break`.